# Count open Office Word Files

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office

I have troubles to find a solution for my problem (I am a really beginner of powershell).

I have to count the Office files which are open on a server.

My situation:

A Service account is connected to a Windows server. A tool works on this session and open a queue of word documents, do such stuff and close the word files. Sometimes the tool can not close the files and then there are many open word files open on the server and it does not work. So I am searching for a solution to check automatically how many open Word files are open with this user.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the site.

The thing your looking for is **open file handles**, and yes there i a tool: [Handle v3.46](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655)

Comment: Hi, 
Thx for the welcome.
with this tool I can not see how many Word sessions I have opened.
I see the open IE sessions or other applications  but not the Office Word documents. The Winword.exe process I see only one time
Or I have not found

Comment: This program find open word files or any other files. If you looking for proccess running, check tasklist ?